# python web scraping, extracting inner element of tag

Tags: python, web-scraping

i want to scrape product and price from an online shopping site, need help in extracting the string written between tags

```
import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
my_url='https://www.flipkart.com/cameras/mirrorless~type/pr?sid=jek%2Cp31'
cl=urlopen(my_url)
page_html=cl.read()
ps=soup(page_html,'html5lib')
ps1=(ps.prettify())
cn=ps.findAll('div',{'class':'_1-2Iqu row'})
len(cn)                     
cn[0].div.div

#output-"<div class="_3wU53n">Canon M50 Mirrorless Camera Body with Single Lens EF-M 15-45 mm ISSTM</div>
#i need Canon M50 Mirrorless Camera Body with Single Lens EF-M 15-45 mm ISSTM
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace cn=ps.findAll('div',{'class':'_1-2Iqu row'}) to cn=ps.findAll('div',{'class':'_1-2Iqu row'},text=True)